# How to handle text/javascript API responses in Delphi (as application/json)?

Tags: json, rest, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

When I make a request to the iTunes search API, the returned content data is formatted as a JSON, but the response's content-type is `text/javascript` instead of `application/json`.

:[image: Headers]

(the green one is from an API that is expected to work, but what I get from iTunes API is marked in red). Thus, Delphi's RESTDebugger receives the response but cannot process it as a valid JSON ('Content is not JSON').

On the IDE (Delphi 11) I am also able to

```
var Resp: IResponse;
Resp := TRequest.New.BaseURL('https://itunes.apple.com')
          .Resource('search?term=' + EditSearch.Text)
          .Accept('application/json')
          .DataSetAdapter(MemTable)
          .get;
```

which gives me that same 200 response, but retrieving `Resp.Content` gets me nothing despite it has content (`Resp.ContentLength` is much greater than zero). Is there a way to convert it to some parseable JSON on Delphi so I can make further processing to it?
Also tried adding `.ContentType('application/json')` to the command above with no success.

Here is the URL for a sample request:
`https://itunes.apple.com/search?media=music&term=talk`

Comment: Using a plain `THTTPClient` shows that the response is plain JSON (even though the `Content-Type` header is `text/javascript; charset=utf-8`, so I guess it's a bug in the REST component(s).

Comment: There was a fix in Delphi 11.3 Patch 1 regarding this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Uwe, applying the 11.3 fix solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).